# Error composing wyrihaximus/ratchet (CakePHP Plugin)

Tags: cakephp, composer-php, ratchet

I'm trying to install WyriHaximus' [Ratchet-Plugin for CakePHP](https://github.com/WyriHaximus/Ratchet) to use WebSockets. I added the following line in Cakes composer.json:

```
 "require": {
        "php": ">=5.2.8",
        "ext-mcrypt": "*",
        "react/socket": "0.3.*|0.4.*",
        "wyrihaximus/ratchet": "dev-master"
    },
    "config": {
        "vendor-dir": "/app/Vendor/"
    },
```

When I run "composer update" in CLI it throws the following Error though I'm running PHP 5.5:

```
Problem 1
  - Installation request for wyrihaximus/ratchet dev-master -> satisfiable by wyrihaximus/ratchet[dev-master].
  - wyrihaximus/ratchet dev-master requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
```

What's the cause and how to fix that?

Comment: If you were indeed running php 5.5 i doubt composer would complain about "requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at that output you don't have PHP5.4 or higher. You can check that with `php -v`.